# removing duplicate rows pandas and remain values from each row different from zero

Tags: pandas

I have this df ( in the real case I have more duplicated rows):

```
    xx    yy    zz   name
A  5      6      0    A
A  0      0     -1    A
C  6      7      5    C
```

How could I merge the 2 rows those indices are the same and keeping only the values different from zero among them? The desired output would be :

```
    xx    yy    zz   name
A  5      6     -1    A
C  6      7      5    C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try `df.where` and groupby `first`

```
df.where(df.ne(0)).groupby(level=0).first()

Out[161]:
    xx   yy   zz name
A  5.0  6.0 -1.0    A
C  6.0  7.0  5.0    C
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df.replace({0: None}).groupby(df.index).max()

    xx  yy  zz  name
A   5   6   7   A
C   6   7   5   C
```

It first replaces the 0 elements by `None`, which is ignored by `max` in the `groupby`.

Comment: @Ami Tavory What if I have a value that is -1?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `replace`, `bfill`, `query` and `duplicated`:

```
df.replace(0, np.NaN).bfill().query('~index.duplicated()')
```

**Output**

```
    xx   yy   zz name
A  5.0  6.0 -1.0    A
C  6.0  7.0  5.0    C
```